# C move string with allocated memory to string in function

Tags: c

I seem to be having trouble doing this, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {                    
    int          test;      
    char        *string;                
    } Data;
Data hello;
int main ()
{
  char *temp;
  size_t a = 100;
  temp = malloc(a*sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;
  temp[count] = 'a';
  count++;
  temp[count] = 'b';
    count++;
    temp[count] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", temp); //shows string

  //hello.string = dup(temp); this fails, as does strdup()[copies mem address]
  printf("%s\n", hello.string);

    return(0);
}
```

My output is

```
ab
seg fault
```

How can I copy this string into the structures string and then call the string from the structure without getting a seg fault?

I've looked around and haven't found any solutions.
Edited: commented out dup

Comment: Please choose a language. Your code can't both be C++ and C.

Comment: I think for strings you should use `strdup()`. `dup` is for file descriptors

Comment: `int count;` --> `int count = 0;`

Comment: What is `dup()`? Please provide a [MCVE] and please don't ever use the word `string` as a variable name anymore.

Comment: Initialize `count` to `0`

Comment: @FirstStep c doesn't use strings as a type, I don't see why using string as a variable name is a problem.

Comment: @Monkleys this was tagged as c++ I think. Sorry then my bad but it is a bad practice to use it anyway

Comment: "*this fails, as does ...*" How does it fail? What errors do you get. When, during run-time or when compiling?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strdup()` function in your program. Like,

```
hello.string = strdup (temp);
```

`strdup` is a Posix function, and `strdup` allocates memory for the new string on the **heap**. It returns a pointer to newly allocated memory into which it has copied the string.

Comment: This adds the pointer to the string in the struct data, I need to return the values.

Comment: @Monkleys: `hello.string` *is* a pointer, which is defined `char *string;`. What do you expect it to save else then an address?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `count` variable wasn't initialized before using. Try this

`int count = 0;`

Comment: This wasn't a problem just yet, easily could have been though. Thanks.